# the status bar background color and text color not working in iOS 13 beta 3 version

Tags: ios, uikit, statusbar, ios13

I tried to change the status bar background color and text color on `iOS 13`, but below code would not have changed status color. it would be grateful if anyone please suggestion for status bar color code part

This my code:

```
UIWindow *_localWindow = [UIApplication sharedApplication].windows[0];
        UIView *statusBarView = [_localWindow.windowScene.statusBarManager performSelector:@selector(createLocalStatusBar)];
        statusBarView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```